# QuickCheck combinators for shrinking lists of length within given bounds

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Is there's a `QuickCheck` function to produce a list whose length is in a given range, similar to what one would achieve with [`hedgegog`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.6/hedgehog-1.0/Hedgehog-Gen.html#v:list), e.g.:

```hs
Gen.list (Range.constant 5 13) someGen
```

I guess one would write something like:

```hs
  do
    n <- choose (minLength, maxLength)
    vectorOf n genA
```

making such function superfluous, but then I wonder whether there are `QuickCheck` combinators to shrink lists whose invariant is that they should have a minimum length. A `shrink` definition like:

```hs
  filter ((minLength <=) . length) [ xs' | xs' <- shrink xs ]
```

seems to be quite inefficient, since we're shrinking terms which we could see in advance that are not valid (since the length will be lower than the minimum threshold).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Gen.html#listOf1) of the [listOf1](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:listOf1) function you see that it is implemented essentially like in your second code snippet, except it uses the [sized](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:sized) function, which means the upper bound decreases as shrinks are performed. I think replacing `1` by your desired minimum bound there should do the trick.

Comment: Right, So the question is: are there any combinators that we could use so that we can write a shrink function that preserves the minimum length invariant?

Comment: No, there is only `listOf1`, which preserves the invariant that the minimum length is 1. You can see it does not call some `listOfn` function internally and also I'm quite familiar with the library and don't think there is one. I stated in my answer how you could write one.

Comment: I meant preserve the invariant during shrinking :)

Comment: Well I guess you first have to write a `newtype` for your list of minimum length, since there is already the instance `Arbitrary a => Arbitrary [a]`. Then as the generator you can supply the generator I suggested. As a shrink function you can provide a modified [shrinkList](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:shrinkList) function (look at the source code) where you `takeWhile (> desiredMin) instead of `0`. I really don't know how much more to tell you to help, the Quickcheck documentation is quite excellent and the source code readable.